# Compiling code on external server (on which I don't have root access)

Tags: c, linux, ssh, terminal, redhat

For the c class I am taking, the c code will be compiled and graded on a redhat linux system, and it is recommended that you ssh to the server, upload, compile and run. This is kind of a pain in the ass and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to automate this, keeping in mind I don't have root access to the server. I'm trying to write a bash script, but I'm having trouble even getting logged in.

Edit: I would like a workflow of:
1) upload the code on the server 2) compile the code 3a) return the compiled file 3b) return compilation errors

Comment: Why do you need to have root access? Also, use *git*. Please verify whether a [tag:c] compiler is installed on the server *gcc* or *clang* and whether or not *git* is installed.

Comment: I was looking into installing software on the server, but I don't have permissions to do so. Not quite sure why you're saying use git, I already do version control on git, but I need to make sure that the code compiles and runs on a specific system.

Comment: If you need to automate anything, use Python. It's easy to learn, easy to use and has many built-in modules for remote access to computers. Install it right on your machine (or even your smartphone), write a script and you're ready!

Comment: You can create a remote repository with *git* and then pull/push to/from the server and it would make it a lot easier and reliable.

Comment: @ForceBru And it's available on 99.9% of linux systems. I would say 100% but I bet there is some strange system that excludes python.

Comment: @iharob That is my current workflow. What I want to be able to do is have a command in terminal (preferably vim) that will:
1) upload the code on the server
2) compile the code
3a) return the compiled file
3b) return compilation errors

Comment: I think you want to find information on `ssh-agent`.

Comment: "I'm having trouble even getting logged in". What exact command(s) did you try and what is the exact trouble? If you tell us someone may be able to help.

Comment: @AndrewWright Add this comment to the question body.

Comment: If you can ssh to the server, that's all you need. Use `scp` to upload the files from your machine, then `ssh servername command you use to compile`

Comment: @Barmar That is my current workflow, but my question is about automating it

Comment: What question do you have about automating it? Just put the commands you would type into a script. If you need to vary some of the parameters, like filenames, make them script arguments and use `$1`, `$2`, etc. to substitute them in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple script that uploads one file and compiles it. You should be able to expand on this to automate more of the workflow.

```
#!/bin/bash
servername=server.school.edu
filename=$1
scp "$filename" "$servername:"
ssh "$servername" gcc -c "$filename"
```

You put this in a script file, make it executable, and use it with:

```
./scriptname project.c
```

Comment: You forgot chmod +x scriptname :)